# Сделать объекты по срокам на активные и неактивные

Tags: битрикс

1С BITRIX

Нужно сделать что бы объекты по срокам от DATE_ACTIVE_FROM до DATE_ACTIVE_TO 
делились на активен товар или неактивен по дате завершения!

Answer (score 1):

Уточните пожалуйста вопрос.

В битриксе дата начала и окончания активности равносильны флагу активности. Если специально не озаботиться, то элемент с истекшей или не начавшейся датой активности просто не выводится.

Если вам надо показывать элемент с какого-то момента, а после какого-то момента добавить ему плашку "срок активности истёк" (но элемент оставлять), то заведите просто новое свойство типа "дата".

Answer (score 1):

Если используете [CIBlockElement::GetList](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php). Для фильтрации (у компонентов можно передать фильтр) есть поля ACTIVE - это только по галке активности и ACTIVE_DATE - активность по дате. 
Если используете \Bitirx\Iblock\ElementTable::GetList для фильтрации поля ACTIVE и пара ACTIVE_FROM и ACTIVE_TO (собственно и в первом варианте ее можно использовать)

Если не для отбора, а уже в момент вывода то запрашивайте ACTIVE, ACTIVE_FROM и ACTIVE_TO и анализируйте их